# Strange Haskell behavior: misplaced error in record syntax?

Tags: haskell

Given the following code, why does Haskell only report an error when it reaches the second `id`?

```
data TypeX = TypeX {
         id :: Int        -- why not the error here?
       , val :: String
       } deriving (Show)
var1 = TypeX 1 "bananas"
var2 = TypeX {
       val = "oranges"
     , id = 2              -- why an error here?
     }
```

The error is:

```
ghci> :l TypeX.lhs
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( TypeX.lhs, interpreted )

TypeX.lhs:8:13:
Ambiguous occurrence ‘id’
It could refer to either ‘Main.id’, defined at TypeX.lhs:2:15
                      or ‘Prelude.id’,
                         imported from ‘Prelude’ at TypeX.lhs:1:1
                         (and originally defined in ‘GHC.Base’)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not an error to define the record field even if it gives a name clash with something imported from another module.  After all, you can still use it by *explicitly* prefixing the current module name:

```
var2 = TypeX {
       val = "oranges"
     , Main.id = 2              -- no more error
     }
```

There's also a language extension `DisambiguateRecordFields` which makes GHC slightly smarter about the field names in record notation, and allows your code as originally written. (But it still won't allow you to define the same field name for two different types in the *same* module.)

Comment: It seems that Haskell is a language in constant flux, adding extensions one after another to cope with "strange" behaviors. I hope many of these extensions will eventually be absorbed as defaults of the language.

Comment: @mljrg We can only hope. It's rather silly when you have extensions that makes your code shorter - but by less than it takes to write the language pragma to enable them. The standards committee has been rather dead for a while, but I hear there are efforts to revive the process.

Comment: Does that mean Haskell risks dying?!

Comment: @mljrg Haskell as an *implementation* (GHC) is fine. But the implementation keeps getting further and further ahead of the written standard (currently Haskell 2010, which was a lot behind GHC even when it was written.)

Comment: So everything that is in GHC but not in Haskell Report 2010 is an extension in GHC, is that so?

Comment: @mljrg For language features, that's mostly the case. Although they separated the language itself from the library once H2010 was finished, and there's a separate committee for changing the libraries, which is in fact doing a *lot* recently - the monad/applicative proposal and foldable/traversable proposal you may have heard of (they made big changes in GHC 7.10) came from that.

Comment: By the way, this behavior is not specific to record fields. You can also define an ordinary top-level value whose name conflicts with an imported identifier, and then you must use a qualified name to refer to either identifier. Useful if you want to export the new value under a name that conflicts with something you imported.